# Excel: Subtotals by year value

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a table in Excel-2013 containing some data similar to this:

```
Year    Month    Electric   Gas         Water    Monthly Totals
2012    Feb      115.49     40.15       82.13    202.70 
2012    Mar      121.26     42.16       86.24    187.48 
2012    Apr      100.10     42.61       81.15    159.10 
2012    May      127.33     44.27       90.55    174.31 
2012    Jun      105.11     44.74       85.21    190.38 
2012    Dec      99.59      51.29       77.70    192.91 
2012    Jan      55.00      97.91       40.00    $196.00 
2013    Feb      104.57     53.86       81.59    205.80 
2013    Mar      81.25      57.75       63.82    212.84 
2014    Oct      49.89      122.10      44.10    262.14 
2014    Dec      51.65      127.72      44.10    223.61 
2014    Nov      51.65      127.72      44.10    240.01
```

I would like to create sub-totals by `Year` for each of the four column headings on the right (Electric, Gas, Water & Monthly Totals) i.e. add add all the gas, water, electrical and monthly totals for 2012/13/14 etc. How might I do this in a fashion that in the case that another month is added, the sum will update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *dynamic tables* for this:

1. Select the range of values.
2. Navigate to the *Insert* tab on your ribbon toolbar.
3. Click the *Dynamic Table* button.
4. Since you've already selected the range, it'd be already set. Click *Accept*.
5. On the newly created sheet, you can drag and drop the `Year` field into the *Rows* panel.
6. Now drag-drop the desired elements you want to sum up into the *Values* panel, or simply check their checkboxes.

You'll end with something like this:

[image: Dynamic table example]

You can do the same for the `Month` field, except that you drag it to the *Rows* panel instead of the `Year` field. You'd need to use a function that compares dates, to sum things up-to-date though.

Comment: That works well, Cheers